# Driver "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" does not support the url "null"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Eclipse threw the following exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Driver "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" does not support the url "null"
```

Here is my context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/advancedweb">
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" debug="99"
    driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    connectionUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/saketramdurbha_test"
    connectionName="root" connectionPassword="pass"
    userTable="adminspass" userNameCol="Username" userCredCol="Password"
    userRoleTable="adminsrole" roleNameCol="Rolename" />
</Context>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`connectionUrl` should be [`connectionURL`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/JDBCRealm-howto.html), like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/advancedweb">
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" debug="99"
    driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/saketramdurbha_test"
    connectionName="root" connectionPassword="pass"
    userTable="adminspass" userNameCol="Username" userCredCol="Password"
    userRoleTable="adminsrole" roleNameCol="Rolename" />
</Context>
```